Автоматическая отправка сообщений пользователю
Я написал бота, который ведёт БД с пользователями и связанными с ними дедлайнами.
Теперь я хочу реализовать следующую функцию: допустим, в 9:00 каждого утра бот пишет пользователю, какие у него установлены сегодня дедлайны.
Для реализации задуманного использую aiogram и aioschedule.
Так выглядит мой код:
async def schedule_deadline():
    global USER_NAME
    aioschedule.every().day.at('11:25').do(check_deadlines_daily)
    while True:
        print(USER_NAME)
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(10)


async def main():
    dp.include_router(router)
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.create_task(schedule_deadline())
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

В check_deadlines_daily я вытаскиваю из таблицы те дедлайны, дата которых совпадает с сегодняшней, а затем отправляю пользователю.
Но проблема в том, что программа даже не входит в эту функцию ровно в то время, в которое указано в aioschedule.every().day.at('11:25').do(check_deadlines_daily).
Вместо этого программа перестаёт работать с ошибкой:
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<schedule_deadline() done, defined at C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\bot_v1\main.py:453> exception=TypeError('Passing coroutines is forbidden, use tasks explicitly.')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\bot_v1\main.py", line 458, in schedule_deadline
    await aioschedule.run_pending()
  File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\bot_v1\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aioschedule\__init__.py", line 544, in run_pending
    await default_scheduler.run_pending()
  File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\bot_v1\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aioschedule\__init__.py", line 111, in run_pending
    return await asyncio.wait(jobs, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 461, in wait
    raise TypeError("Passing coroutines is forbidden, use tasks explicitly.")
TypeError: Passing coroutines is forbidden, use tasks explicitly.

В чём может быть проблема?

наверняка check_deadlines_daily асинхронная функция, о чем вам и сообщают, т.к, вы передаете корутину. Что за глобал, к слову? Глобалы - плохо. Как вам идея выучить питон, а потом лезть писать ботов с шедулерами, базами данных и асинхронщиной?

да я понимаю, что у меня говнокод и не лез бы сюда, если бы не требовали. в глобале я храню юзернейм, чтобы в чек_дедлайнс отправить пользователю сообщение. если сама функцию должна быть неасинхронной, то мне надо в отдельном методе отправлять сообщение пользователю?

можно использовать apscheduler вместо вашего, у него вроде с этим все ок. Так у вас глобал один на всю программу

Используй apschedule
   from apschedule import AsyncIOScheduler

   async def deadline():
      scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
      scheduler.add_job(check_deadlines_daily, hour=11, minute=25)
      scheduler.start()

   async def on_startup(_):
       loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
       loop.create_task(deadline())

Думаю так будет легче
